# VBA how to display two msgbox with sign?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim fg As Double
Dim msg1 As String
Dim msg2 As String
Dim result As Integer
Dim percent As Double


fg = Cells(8, 10).Value

percent = Application.WorksheetFunction.roundup(fg * 100, 2)


msg1 = "Fat as percentage of calories consumed:" & percent & "%"
msg2 = "Recommended total fat intake: less than 30% of total calories."
msg3 = "you are suggested to change your food choice to lower the fat"
If fg > 0.3 Then
    MsgBox msg1
    MsgBox msg2, vbExclamation
    result=MsgBox msg3, vbYesNo
    
    If result = vbYes Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Meal Planner").Activate
    end if
    If result = vbNo Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DAILY LOG").Activate
    End If
    
    
    
End If

If fg < 0.3 Then MsgBox (msg1)



End Sub
```

Why does the program fail to show sheet "Weekly Meal Planner" when I click OK

Comment: Why do you need to put them both on one line?

Comment: @braX because i want to display both msg2 and msg1 when fg>0.3

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to put them both on the same line.

Here's how an if statement works.

```
If fg > 0.3 Then 
  MsgBox msg2, vbExclamation
  MsgBox msg1
End If
```

`MsgBox` uses parenthesis only when you need it to return a value:

```
Dim result as Variant
result = MsgBox(msg3, vbYesNo)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function

To use it as a `Subroutine`, do not use parenthesis.

```
MsgBox "test"
```

To use it as a `Function`, include parenthesis.

```
result = MsgBox("test")
```

You can also use an icon and a button choice:

```
result = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
```

Comment: there is still a snytax error in the line MsgBox(msg2, vbExclamation)

Comment: Remove the parenthesis.

Comment: why cant display the sheet "Weekly Meal Planner" when I kick ok?

Comment: ...and let's just hope that `Cells(8, 10).Value` returns a numeric value, or the whole thing will crash.